# Is there a generally agreed short notation for "a points to b"

Tags: notation

Is there a conventional symbol for "points to" or "is a pointer to". I've been using a short right arrow; for example "a is a pointer to b" would be (approximately)

```
a -> b
```

but I wonder whether a short double right arrow would be better:

```
a => b
```

Best of all would be to know, and use, a universally-accepted standard symbol, if there is one?

Comment: In which context? Programming languages? Generating functions? ...? (Note that all arrow symbols are heavily overloaded in CS.)

Comment: Whatever symbol you choose, define it before you use it first. "Let $a\to b$ denote that $a$ points to $b$."

Comment: @Raphael : Very true. Maybe a hook or a harpoon might be better... :-)

Comment: @DaveClarke : Yes, of course, I'd do that as a matter of course, but it would be nice to avoid the *that's a strange notation* syndrome.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your question is that [pointers and pointers semantics
may vary significantly from language to language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)). Even your question
is ambiguous. So you are asking a question about notation, i.e., about
syntax, which is largely a matter of arbitrary convention, but it is
not even clear what is the semantics intended by your question.

You apparently use as synonyms "a points to b", "a is a pointer to b",
"a -> b". But I am not sure what is the meaning and context. Does it
assert that `a` is actually pointing to `b` (descriptive meaning) or
does it modify the data so that `a` is now pointing to `b` (imperative
meaning). Then what is `b`, or what can `b` be. Is it the location of
some value, or is it the value of whatever is pointed by `a`. Is it
intended to be part of a programming language syntax, or of the
metalanguage used to discuss about programs.

If you have `a -> b` and `c -> b`, does it imply that `a = c`. Furthermore, if `a` and `c` are pointers, what is the meaning of
`a = c`? See for example "[shallow and deep equality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator#Object_identity_vs._content_equality)".

Actually all this is often an issue of designation of container and
content. A pointer is a designation for a container (a memory
location, for example), and the content of that container may vary.
But the content may also include container designation.

One major problem is that notations are often ambiguous as they often
do not clearly distinguish between container and content, often implicitly
casting one into the other.

If you consider a variable, say an integer variable `x` in some
programmning language, this variable is actually a container where you
can change the content (which is supposed to be an integer). But,
within the scope of its declaration, `x` will always be the same
container. An integer variable is actually a pointer constant: a
location designator.

Then, can you write `x -> 3` to indicate that `x` denotes a pointer
constant toward a location containing the value `3`?

Or is the arrow supposed to point on the right to whatever container
is "designated" by the expression on the left. But if you have a
pointer constant (i.e. a pointer value) on the left, what is the
meaning of the notation.

Now, you can have pointer variables, which may contain a
container. They can appear through explicit declaration, or via other
mechanism such as parameter passing by reference.

When sharing a meal with other people, you can ask for the bottle or
for the wine. It will mean the same. But in programming context, more
precision may be needed.

So my first reaction to your question is: *Could you be more precise
about the semantics you intend to express, before you suggest agreeing
on a standard notation?*

Another minor point is that, while asking your question, you seem to
suggest that a double shafted arrow `=>` would be better than a single
shafted on `->`. But you do not give any hint as to why it might be
better. This makes me uneasy, especially wen I am not even sure of
what you want to talk about, and in what context.

Since this is supposed to be an answer rather than further questions,
I would suggest that the lack of a standard may well come from the
fact that programming languages vary significantly in their use of
pointers, and on the semantics attached to various constructs using
pointers. We can hardly standardize notation when what is to be denoted is
not itself standardized.

Hence, our only recourse is to choose for ourselves a notation that is intuitive and
consistent in its intended context, and define it precisely together
with the associated semantics. I insist on consistency since there are
many things you may want to do with pointers, and it is important
that the notations for each remain intuitive, and that they combine
naturally and consistently. The issue of equality is an example.

Comment: Thank you for helping me clarify my thoughts. `a => b` would be a statement that a points to be, not an assignment, and the double-shafted arrow was an off-the cuff idea to allow unambiguous mixing of pointer statements and logical implication.

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is no standard, accepted notation.  Different papers tend to use different notations.  So, choose one that is suitable for your needs and define it before using it.

Here are some examples of notations I've seen used, in different contexts:

- I've seen some papers on points-to analysis use $\text{pt}(v)$ to refer to the set of objects that $v$ might point to.  This allows you to write $b \in \text{pt}(a)$ if you want to say that $a$ points to $b$.  This is convenient in that domain, because points-to analysis is a "may" analysis: for each variable $v$, it keeps track of all the objects that $v$ could potentially point to (along some feasible path of the program).
- As another notation, in some papers I've seen people draw heap graphs, where each vertex represents a variable and each edge represents a points-to relationship.
- As yet another notation, I've seen people use notation like $a \mapsto b$ to indicate that $a$ points to $b$.
- Steensgaard's [seminal paper on points-to analysis](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse503/10wi/readings/steensgaard-popl96.pdf) used a notation like $A \vdash x : \text{ref}(\alpha)$ to mean, very roughly, that $x$ points to $\alpha$, more or less.  Warning: this is not really an accurate statement of what that notation means.  (Actually, $\alpha$ is a type -- see the original paper for details, before trying to use notation like this.)

There are probably many others as well.

My advice is to know your audience, choose a notation that will work well for your purposes, and use that.  You might read other papers that are working in a similar area and see what notation they use, and try to use something similar if it is suitable for your needs, in hopes of choosing something familiar to your audience.  But whatever you do, define your notation before first use, as there is no absolute accepted standard here.